# Usb with linux fails when boot

Tags: linux, boot, usb, amd-ryzen

I'm having a big problem with my pc. I have an usb with linux installed but every time I boot it outputs an error. It's weird because it doesn't do that on others pc. First of all starts doing something like `AMD-Vi: Completion-wait loop timed out`.

After that appears `couldn't allocate usb_device`. After some time it looks like it finally boots but it stops and show `BusyBox v1.30.1 (Debian 1:1.30.1-4) buil-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands`
I don't know how to solve this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: There are a number of settings in BIOS that might need to be changed. It is also possible you're using the wrong version (32-bit vs. 64-bit) of Linux. More information on the BIOS settings of successful and unsuccessful PC's would help.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks, I'm sure the problem isn't the architecture, because both PC are using 64 bits. I'll check the bios settings and see if I can fix this